# How to get posts on both the home page and another page? functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

The `|| is_page(7)` doesn't effect that page. I also tried:
`or is_page(7)`, `or is_page('7')`, `|| is_page('reading-list')`
Both the home page and the reading list page use the `index.php` file.
How do I get the posts to show up on the Reading List page?

Part of `functions.php` file:

```
 add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

    function my_get_posts( $query ) {

        if ( is_home() || is_page(7) && $query->is_main_query() )
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'article') );

        return $query;
    }
```

Part of `index.php` file:

```
        <?php
            if (have_posts()) :
                while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <article class="post">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </article>

                <?php endwhile;

                else :
                    echo '<p>No content found</p>'; 
                endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: So, what specifically is happening currently that you want different? What lists currently on the "Reading List" page? (Is the "reading list" page just a page you've set up via the WP "Pages" dashboard)? This is fairly unclear.

Comment: Your logic in the `if` may need some parenthesis. Do you mean: `if ( (is_home() || is_page(7)) && $query->is_main_query() )` ?

Comment: @cale_b The "Reading List" is a page I set up via the WP "Pages: dashboard. What is happening on the "Reading List" page is that it only displays the page title and no posts. The home page works as wanted.

Comment: `@Andy C` I tried using parenthesis where you suggested, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Alexander - you are NOT going to get the desired results this way.  I'd recommend reading about either using a custom loop (with a custom template), or else leveraging the built-in WP "archive" system, including the ability to override the archive with your own custom archive.

Comment: @ cale_b - I tried making a custom page template ('page-readinglist.php') with the code from the 'index.php' file and having the "Reading List" WP page use that template. It didn't work. Is that what you're getting at or something a bit different with the custom loop? I'm still sort of new to coding.